# Is it possible to exploit this cors?

Tags: cors, sub-domain, reflected-xss

I found an xss on `subdomain.example.com` and i verified that the domain `api.example.com` accepts `subdomain.example.com` as valid origin. Can i exploit this as cors by inserting a CORS script in `subdomain.example.com` and send the link to victim?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I suggest you code a PoC to confirm, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @paj28,
Thanks for confirming it. As i was able to inject a `<script src` tag, do you know a javascript cors code that works with that? The ones i tried were not working.

Comment: Just use XmlHttpRequest, when you do it cross-domain, CORS kicks in automatically